# Model placement of object on the edges of hexagons

Tags: javascript, geometry, hexagonal-tiles

I have a field of hexagons  that are arragned gapless (like this: http://www.imec.be/ScientificReport/SR2007/html/afbeeldingen/SR030F1.jpg)

One hexagon is represented by the class `Hexagon`.

My problem is now that I want to "place" certain objects on the corners and edges of the hexagons. Obviosly, placing it (for example) on the top edge of a hexagon requires to set it on the adjacent hexagon's bottom edge, too.

But I do not want to handle multiple placements representing the same position from different view points.

Do you know a nicer way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Leo

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this seems to answer my question very well:

http://www.mattpalmerlee.com/2012/04/10/creating-a-hex-grid-for-html5-games-in-javascript/